# Regex to extract path tree from window.pathname

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I access Javascript's `window.pathname` and get `/you/are/here`.

Is it possible to construct a regular expression that incrementally matches each part of the path starting from the beginning? In other words, `my_regex.exec(window.pathname)` would return an array of matches like this:

```
["/you", "/you/are", "/you/are/here", index: 0, input: "/you/are/here"]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, regular expressions will not do it. You should match "/[a-zA-Z0-9]+" ( or something that captures the identifiers) and then create the strings by looping over the matches.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run it like this:

```
location.pathname.match(/\w+/g)
```

That should return an array with all whole words. Of course, a path can also consist of spaces and underscores, as well as % in case of url encoding. So to cover those as well:

```
location.pathname.match(/[\w_\s.%]+/g)
```

The bracket creates a character class where any of the characters between the brackets are considered part of the character.
Inside the class we have \w for all regular characters (A-Za-z0-9), followed by underscore(_); any type of space (\s); a period (.); and finally a percentage sign (%).
After the character class we add + to say the want to find at least one, but as many as possible.
The g flag at the end forces it to become global, which should return an array with all hits.

Comment: Thanks, but this returns `["you", "are", "here"]`, not what I specified in my question.

Comment: In your second example it would be simpler to use `/[^/]/g` as that will catch anything but a slash, but in that case you might as well use `string.split('/')`. @Devin It's impossible to do what you're looking for using regex alone.

Comment: Devin, you're right, I overlooked the last part.
@RevanProdigalKnight Good points, you are absolutely correct :)